# Java Spring boot - Rest Template (request with no response, no error)

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, response, resttemplate

I'm trying to create a GET request to retrieve commercial flights from latam. But I only get the answer through insomnia/postman...

I'm making the request through RestTemplate in Java, as shown below:

```
public class LatamRequest {

    public void consumerAPILatam(){
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        //h.ttps://www.latamairlines.com/bff/air-offers/offers/search
        UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                .scheme("https")
                .host("www.latamairlines.com")
                .path("bff/air-offers/offers/search")
                .queryParam("sort","RECOMMENDED")
                .queryParam("cabinType","Economy")
                .queryParam("origin","GRU")
                .queryParam("destination","BSB")
                .queryParam("inFlightDate","null")
                .queryParam("inFrom","null")
                .queryParam("inOfferId","null")
                .queryParam("outFlightDate","null")
                .queryParam("outFrom","2022-11-15T15%3A00%3A00.000Z")
                .queryParam("outOfferId","null")
                .queryParam("adult","1")
                .queryParam("child","0")
                .queryParam("infant","0")
                .queryParam("redemption","true")
                .build();

        headers.set("User-Agent", "test");
        headers.set("Accept", "*/*");
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.set("X-latam-App-Session-Id", "84196897-1687-4d8c-8e63-083091ac204f");
        headers.set("X-latam-Action-Name", "search-result.flightselection.offers-search");
        headers.set("X-latam-Application-Name", "web-air-offers");
        headers.set("X-latam-Client-Name", "web-air-offers");
        headers.set("X-latam-Track-Id", "3a4ae189-e218-4606-bd9e-8b17efc93463");
        headers.set("X-latam-Request-Id", "ff44ef24-e6d0-4cb0-984c-df1db18cee19");
        headers.set("X-latam-Application-Country", "BR");
        headers.set("X-latam-Application-Oc", "br");
        headers.set("X-latam-Application-Lang", "pt");

        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange(uri.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class); //todo: No response, no error... 
        System.out.println(response);
    }

}
```

I don't get any response or status after executing the above block. OBS: With the same parameters and headers I get status 200 in postman or insomnia.

I've tried several ways, but I can't get a response. Does anyone have any ideas for a more effective debug?

Comment: hello Khodadadi, I didn't understand what I should have returned... I expected the return in json from the server in the "response" object

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you don't get any response and no exception is because the server side gets your request and keeps holding it and doesn't respond. So you are still in a waiting mode. I ran your request from java code using different http client but used exact your params and I noticed that response never returns. I waited for over 10 minutes and I saw that the program was still running. So I modified the code and added connection timeout for 5 sec and read timeout for 30 seconds. When I ran it it I got read timeout exception after 30 seconds. So the code manages to connect to server side, but server side just doesn't respond. So you are in endless wait. So, I don't know why it works from postman. May be some headers values issues.

Comment: Thanks for the support Michael.
When I removed the User-Agent header I got a response with status 404 (Bad request).
When I remove the "X-latam-Track-Id" I get a response saying that the header is missing.
I believe the headers are giving me this headache. haha